# how to create json object in angular2

Tags: json, angular

i want to create J SON object in angular2 like this:

```
{ "classifications": [ 
                      { "type1" : [{"name":"text"},{"name":"text2"},{"name":"text2"}]} , 
                      { "type2" : [{"name":"image"},{"name":"img2"},{"name":"img3"},{"name":"img4"}]} ,
                      { "type3" : [{"name":"mp3"}]}
                      ] 
        }
```

is this the right way or not?? if not then how to make it and how to get data from this J SON object??

Comment: What is not working? Do you get an error?

Comment: No, just i don't sure about this way and i don't know how to get data from it to test

Comment: You don't need the `"` for the keys but besides that it should be fine.

Comment: For example i want to get values of type1 or just the first value of type1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let x = { "classifications": [ 
                      { "type1" : [{"name":"text"},{"name":"text2"},{"name":"text2"}]} , 
                      { "type2" : [{"name":"image"},{"name":"img2"},{"name":"img3"},{"name":"img4"}]} ,
                      { "type3" : [{"name":"mp3"}]}
                      ] 
        }

console.log(x.classifications[0].type1[0].name);
```

Comment: this make an error : Property 'type1' does not exist on type '{ "type1": { "name": string; }[]; } | { "type2": { "name": string; }[]; } | { "type3": { "name": ...'.

Comment: thanks really it works , but i don't know why eclipse marks it as an syntax error

Comment: You can try `console.log(x['classifications'][0]['type1'][0]['name']);`

Comment: If this answers your question, you can accept it using the white checkmark below the up-down-vote buttons to indicate that your problem is solved. Thanks.